# log4j.properties file disappears in the project/Classes location

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm configuring `log4j` in my standalone Java project. I created the property file under `project/classes` folder but everyday when I run the my application I get errors like

```java
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (cafcontroller.CAFController).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Then when I check the project/classes folder I find the `log4j.properties` file missing. Then I create one manually in it. I don't understand why it goes missing.

Please help me to fix this .

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you rebuild your project, classes folder gets completely refreshed, deleting and recreating all the class files. Put your `log4j.properties` file inside your `project/src` folder. It will be copied to your classes folder on rebuild.